# MacOS - Visual Studio 2019 Typescript / Sass compiler

Tags: typescript, macos, sass, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to get my TypeScript and Scss to compile to Javascript and css respectively in Visual Studio 2019 (MVC .Net Core)
I can't find a working compiler anywhere. Does anyone know how it's done on MacOS?

Answer (score 1):

The answer for now seems to be using NPM to install typescript and sass through the terminal and then using tsc *.ts --watch and sass [nameoffile].scss [nameoffile].css --watch to compile typescript and scss files. For from the ideal situation but it works great.